# System is not opening

Tags: 16.04

I just updated my system and I rebooted it, but it is not opening, it is showing ubuntu and showing dotted lines below. I am using 16.04 version of Ubuntu. I am attaching the picture here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Long Press the power button and force shutdown it. Try to power on after few minutes (About 10-12 minutes). Also unplug any other devices like USB Stick etc if available.